# Ads: Ad failed to load : 3

Tags: android, admob

I have created a new google play developer account.And I published my app 3-4 days ago. Banner and interstitial has working on emulator but real time not working. And ı get this error :failed to load ad:3 that's mean is Admob No fill from ad server. But what should I do, I don't know?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, everything is brand new, yet again "failed to load ad:3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may have to wait a few days. My ads are now appearing. I think we have to be patient.